# Sending data through GET method when DATA is saved in mongoose Atlas

Tags: javascript, post, mongoose, promise, get

I have a question :)

My question is the following how can I wait the information to be saved in the Mongoose Database before sending the Database information from a GET method. More over the data are saved in a POST method, and the GET method is done outside the POST method.

The problem is when the console.log in the GET method appears before the console.log to check if the data is saved.

Here is my code :

```
// Variables needed to access the API 
const API_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:";
const API_key = process.env.GOOGLE_BOOKS_APIKEY;

// Connection to the Google Books API to retrieve dataObject
app.post('/server', async(req,res)=>{
// receive input send by client side (used it to access pictures from google API and also )
dataObject = req.body;
const response_books_api = await fetch(`${API_url}${dataObject.book_entry.isbn}&key=${API_key}`);
try {
  const json_books_api = await response_books_api.json();
  console.log(json_books_api);
  res.send(json_books_api);
  console.log(json_books_api.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail);
   // Save data from the userInput in Mongoose Atlas database
const books = new Books({
book_name: dataObject.book_entry.book_name,
subtitle: dataObject.book_entry.subtitle,
author: dataObject.book_entry.author,
publishing_date: dataObject.book_entry.publishing_date,
publishing_house: dataObject.book_entry.publishing_house,
isbn: dataObject.book_entry.isbn,
collection_data: dataObject.book_entry.collection,
description: dataObject.book_entry.description,

});

const images = new Images({
imageUrl: json_books_api.items[0].volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail,
})


books.save().then(()=>{
  console.log('data successfully posted!')
  // res.status(201).json({
  //     message: 'data successfully posted!',
  // });
}).catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error);
    // res.status(400).json({
    //     error: error,
    // })
    });
function send_image(){
  images.save().then(()=>{
console.log('data successfully posted!')
  // res.status(201).json({
  //     message: 'data successfully posted!',
  // });
  }).catch((error)=>{
   console.log(error);
   // res.status(400).json({
   //     error: error,
   // })
 });
}


  } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
  }


 });



 // send the book information from database to get it on the client side

 app.get('/server/books',(req,res)=>{
  Books.find().then(
   (books) =>{
    res.status(200).json(books);
    }
   ).catch(
   (error) =>{
    console.log(error);
      res.statut(400).json({
      error: error
    });
   }
 );
 });

// send the imageURL from database to get it on the client side
app.get('/server/images',(req,res)=>{
  Images.find().then(
    (images) =>{
      res.status(200).json(images);
       console.log('ok send')
    }
   ).catch(
    (error) =>{
      console.log(error);
      res.statut(400).json({
        error: error
      });
    }
  );
})
```

Comment: No one to help me ,

Comment: Hi Mohamed, 
I saw your other question about getting no help. I will try and help here. I think your question is too difficult to understand, so few people are looking at it. Can you tell me which GET and POST requests you are making and how they are being called in your front end? Sample post data would be useful too. I will then try and help you to reformat the question and answer it.